# Instead of git checkout file one by one, checkout a whole commit

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-checkout

I have a situation where I committed to a branch B1. In the commit I have several files. Now I want those files to be copied to a Branch B2.

Actually I am using the following command for each file in the commit on my current branch B2:

```
 $ git checkout B1 path/to/file1
 $ git checkout B1 path/to/file2
 ......
 $ git checkout B1 path/to/fileN
```

I guess that there should be a syntax that will allow me to directly checkout the specific commit from branch B1 to branch B2. I tried several solutions but they are rewriting the whole branch which I do not want, nor history of the all files. I only want the state of the file in the particular commit. Overwriting is not a problem.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want to get "the complete repo as it is in B1" ? or "only the files modified in the last commit on B1" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout B1 .
```

You have to specify *a* path to get what you want, so `.` is a path that specifies the current directory.

Comment: I forget to mention that all the files are not in the same directory, and do not necessarily have same extensions

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of files modified in commit `xyz`, run :

```
# get only the names for the diff between xyz's parent and xyz :
git diff --name-only xyz^ xyz
```

If you want to checkout these files only :

```
git checkout B1 -- $(git diff --name-only xyz^ xyz)

# for example : the files modified in the last commit on B2 :
git checkout B1 -- $(git diff --name-only B2^ B2)
```

Comment: will try and if works will mark it as best answer